# Why is my UI Button displaying a button clicked message when it has not ben clicked?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GUIScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    string buttonText = "Ok!";

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.skin.button.fontSize = 50;

        GUI.contentColor = Color.yellow;
        GUI.backgroundColor = Color.blue;

        var textsize3 = GUI.skin.button.CalcSize(new GUIContent(buttonText));

        Rect buttRect = new Rect(0, 600, textsize3.x, textsize3.y);

        if (GUI.Button(buttRect, buttonText)) ;
        {
            print("Butt clicked");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this in Unity 3D 2017.3 the console constantly displays a button clicked message even when there is no mouse click. Anybody can say why this happens?

Comment: probably because you have a semicolon at the end of your if statement? `if (GUI.Button(buttRect, buttonText)) **;**`

Comment: The extra semicolon at the end of the `if` makes its body empty! And the following print becomes, in fact, unconditional. Remove that semicolon.

Comment: You are correct! My bad.:(